# Python code to swap first and last letters in string

Tags: python, string, python-2.x

Given a string, return a new string where the first and last chars have been exchanged.

```
front_back('code') → 'eodc'
front_back('a') → 'a'
front_back('ab') → 'ba'
```

The above is one of the problems provided on www.codingBat.com I was attempting to solve and below is the code I wrote to do so.

```
def front_back(str):     
    str = list(str)
    first = [str[0]]
    last = [str[-1]]
    middle = str[1:-1]
    print ''.join (last + middle + first)
```

Now this code seems to work properly when I run it in python 2.7 on my computer but when running it on code bat I get the following error: "Error:list index out of range"

Now I think I have a pretty good idea of what this error means, but I don't understand why I am getting it due to the fact any indexes I am referencing are basically guaranteed to be in string of at least 2 characters.

Comment: `str[1:-1]` will go out of range for `'a'` since only index `[0]` and `[-1]` are valid

Comment: I get the same error even when substituting [0] for [1]. I understand the code wouldn't work as intended if middle was equal to that index range, but my point is it still gives me the list index out of range error.

Answer (score 3):

You probably got an `IndexError` for an empty string (`''`) as `str[0]` would be out of range in that case. As written, your code would also produce an invalid result for a 1-character string. To fix it, you can `return` the original string if its length is < 2. Also, it would be much simpler (and faster) to use string slicing:

```
def front_back(string):
    if len(string) < 2:
        return string
    return string[-1] + string[1:-1] + string[0]
```

(As a side note, don't use `str` for a variable name as it'll shadow the [built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) `str` function).

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple to avoid the special cases:

```
def front_back(string):
    array = list(string)
    if array:
        array[0], array[-1] = array[-1], array[0]
    return "".join(array)
```

Or in current Python 3:

```
def front_back(string):
    if array := list(string):
        array[0], array[-1] = array[-1], array[0]
    return "".join(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with 1 character, ie. `front_back('a') → 'a'`. Consider how you could adjust your function to account for this case.

EDIT: I did not like the efficiency or generality of the other answers, so I'll post my solution below:

```
def front_back(str):
    return ''.join([x if i not in [0,len(str)-1] else str[len(str)-i-1] for i,x in enumerate(str) ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the website uses a series of random/pseudorandom characters to determine if your code gives the correct output. If so then a string of `len() == 1` would return incorrectly. i.e. `'h' return 'hh'`. I have modified the code to correct this. Assuming that the website also asked you to return the data rather that print I also accounted for that. Good luck!

```
def front_back(str):
    if len(str) > 1:
        str = list(str)
        first = [str[0]]
        last = [str[-1]]
        middle = str[1:-1]
        return ''.join (last + middle + first)
    else:
        return str

print front_back('h')
```

Comment: I get the following error when running the above code in replacement of mine:  Error:can only concatenate list (not "str") to list which I think is just due to 'middle' not being a list so I made it one, now I get same error as before: "List index out of range"

Comment: I don't know what version of python this website is running but this code works perfectly on `python2, 3`. I have changed the code nonetheless.

Comment: Here is a link to the practice problem in case anyone wants to try it: http://codingbat.com/prob/p153599